# (lldb) po self.storyboard nil

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uistoryboard

How/when can a UIViewController return `self.storyboard` nil.

I am trying to instantiate a ViewController with:

```
self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier
```

But self.storyboard is nil?
Note: the plist is set to the right storyboard.

Comment: `If the view controller was not instantiated from a storyboard, this property is nil.` (from the doc). How is created your `UIViewController`?

Comment: You are right, the ViewController is created in code an therefore the storyboard is nil. The answer is to create you own instance.

Comment: This sounds like it's probably an X/Y problem.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/storyboard), `UIViewController`'s `storyboard` property represents the storyboard from which the view controller originated.  It returns an optional `UIStoryboard` instance which is `nil` if the view controller was not instantiated from a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let localStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

Comment: This actually worked for me.  I am using storyboard for only parts of my app --- not including the rootViewController.

Comment: don't thumbs down as this is a valid approach.